# Is it possible to Remote Desktop to Console 0 of a remote XP SP3 machine using mstsc.exe /admin?

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, windows-xp

Is it possible to Remote Desktop to Console 0 of a remote XP Pro SP3 machine from an XP Pro SP3 machine using mstsc.exe /admin?  I am getting " ... maximum terminal connections reached ... " even with the /admin option.

I am starting to think that once the maximum terminal connections are reached on XP Pro SP3 it just won't let anyone remotely connect at all.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know only one RDP connection is allowed to XP, which is the console session.

Comment: Correct, the "workstation" OSs (XP, Vista, 7) only allow one RDP session and it is the console session.  That is why when you RDP to the machine, at the physical screen you are locked out.